# Terraform AWS - How to dynamically assign availability zones to number of instances created

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've been having trouble trying to dynamically assign availability zones to the ec2 instances I create via Terraform.

Context : I've created a shell script to take in user input to specify the number of instances to create. Based on the number of instances, I want to assign each created instance to a specific availability zone using either a for or for_each loop.

shell script

```
##create ec2 on AWS
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting EC2 Set up..."

echo "Specify number of EC2 instances to create : "
read number_of_instances

echo "You made a request for $number_of_instances to be created"

terraform validate

terraform apply -var instance_count=${number_of_instances}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2-instance" {
  ami             = var.ami
  count           = var.instance_count
  key_name        = var.key_name
  instance_type   = var.instance_type
  subnet_id       = var.subnet_id
  security_groups = [data.aws_security_group.my-sec-group.id]

  availability_zone = ##How do I dynamically assign an availability zone here##

  tags = {
    Name    = "my-ec2-instance-tag${count.index + 1}"
    Project = "my terraform project"
  }
}
```

Expected output for my ec2:

If i want 2 instances created

- my-ec2-instance1 should be assigned to ap-southeast-1a
- my-ec2-instance2 should be assigned to ap-southeast-1b

If i want 3 instances created

- my-ec2-instance1 should be assigned to ap-southeast-1a
- my-ec2-instance2 should be assigned to ap-southeast-1b
- my-ec2-instance3 should be assigned to ap-southeast-1c

If i want 5 instances created

- my-ec2-instance1 should be assigned to ap-southeast-1a
- my-ec2-instance2 should be assigned to ap-southeast-1b
- my-ec2-instance3 should be assigned to ap-southeast-1c
- my-ec2-instance4 should be assigned to ap-southeast-1a
- my-ec2-instance5 should be assigned to ap-southeast-1b

What I've tried so far :

variable.tf

```
variable "availability_zone_map" {
    description = "Availability zone for instance"
    type        = map
    default     = {
        "ap-southeast-1a" = 1 
        "ap-southeast-1b" = 2
        "ap-southeast-1c" = 3
    }
        
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2-instance" {
  ami             = var.ami
  count           = var.instance_count
  key_name        = var.key_name
  instance_type   = var.instance_type
  subnet_id       = var.subnet_id
  security_groups = [data.aws_security_group.my-sec-group.id]
  for_each        = var.availability_zone_map
  availability_zone = each.key

  tags = {
    Name    = "my-ec2-instance-tag${count.index + 1}"
    Project = "my terraform project"
  }
}
```

This is definitely wrong as a resource will not be able to take in count and for_each at the same time.

Would appreciate if anyone could help me get around this? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are doing this exactly like this? The better way would be to create AutoScaling group spanning three AZs and let AWS manage spread. Your current setup is not fault tolerant as it fixes instances to specific AZs, which may already be running at capacity or be simply non-accessible.

Comment: @Marcin Hi. Actually yes! my intention was actually to achieve autoscaling but didn't know how to do that (maybe because I wasnt asking the right questions to come to that conclusion) do i achieve that - considering that the number of instances will always change as according to user input?

Comment: @Marcin in my case I am running Unreal Engine applications and I am adding one app per instance, so there is no concept of load balancing as I have one user per ec2. I have come across this problem where when creating ec2s with terraform I need to know what zone it will be created on so I can create and attach ESB on the same zone. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the intent is to create an autoscaling group in AWS.

For that you need two components:

- [aws_launch_template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_template.html)
- [aws_autoscaling_group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html)

Thus, instead of your `"my-ec2-instance` your would create corresponding `aws_launch_template`.

The template would be references in attribute `launch_template` of the ASG.

The `instance_count` would be assigned to `desired_capacity` of the ASG.

Comment: ok cool. But i've yet to understand if you could help me out here. In simple terms, what is the difference between using aws_instance vs aws_launch_templace? The documentation only mentions this: "Provides an EC2 launch template resource. Can be used to create instances or auto scaling groups."

Comment: @Syabster Hi. Template is like a blueprint of your instances. ASG will use the template/blueprint to launch instances automatically. All their settings will be based on the template.

Comment: Great, so technically, some of the attributes in my existing aws_instance resource could be used in the aws_launch_template resource too yes? with the exception of the AZs.

Comment: @Syabster That's correct. Its basically one to one mapping between template and instance settings. The AZs can be specified in ASG.

Comment: Awesome! Let me try this out first before declaring this as an answer! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Syabster No problem. The docs linked have examples with both template and asg.

Answer (score 2):

If the intention is to use ASG then Marcin's answer is the best direction.

If you still want to manage EC2 instances manually due to what ever reason (I was in similar situation where ASG was not an option) then following will get you what you want.

```
variable "availability_zones" {
    description = "Availability zones for instance"
    type        = list
    default     = [
        "ap-southeast-1a" = 1 
        "ap-southeast-1b" = 2
        "ap-southeast-1c" = 3
    ]
        
}

resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2-instance" {
  ami             = var.ami
  count           = var.instance_count
  key_name        = var.key_name
  instance_type   = var.instance_type
  subnet_id       = var.subnet_id
  security_groups = [data.aws_security_group.my-sec-group.id]
  availability_zone = var.availability_zones[ count %  var.instance_count]

  tags = {
    Name    = "my-ec2-instance-tag${count.index + 1}"
    Project = "my terraform project"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this too! Yes, the intension was to achieve autoscaling. But please leave this answer here! I think it might help others if ASG is not an option. Then this would be useful. :)